# Изменить текст label из другого потока на полученное значение от метода класса

Tags: c#, winforms

Всё перетыкал - какая то кракозябра получается и всё равно форма виснет xD

```
new Thread(() => Invoke(new Delegate(() => { label1.Text = MyClass.ClassMethod(); }))).Start();
```

UPD: Вот так вышло, а как бы лаконичнее что ли ?

```
        new Thread(() => test()).Start();
    ........
    private void test() 
    {
        var aaa = MyClass.ClassMethod();

        Invoke(new Delegate(() => { label1.Text = aaa; }));
    }
```

Comment: `ClassMethod()` долго выполняется? Если да, нужно выполнить его _перед_ вызовом `Invoke`. Всё, что внутри `Invoke` выполняется в GUI-потоке. Там должно быть только элементарное присваивание свойству контрола готового значения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да - там ожидание ответа от сервера

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо! Работает xD Как и обычно после ваших советов. А то я уже про InvokeRequired начал читать - думал это. А вот как мою строчку так раскидать, чтобы тоже самое было, а то у меня в несколько строк и отдельным методом. Ну т.е. коротко и правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassMethod()` долго выполняется? Если да, нужно выполнить его перед вызовом `Invoke`. Всё, что внутри `Invoke` выполняется в GUI-потоке. Там должно быть только элементарное присваивание свойству контрола готового значения.

Кратко код можно оформить следующим образом:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    var result = MyClass.ClassMethod();
    Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = result));
})
.Start();
```

Ещё короче и удобнее использовать таски. Ныне это рекомендуемый подход вместо тредов.

```
label1.Text = await Task.Run(() => MyClass.ClassMethod());
```

При этом нужно добавить `async` в сигнатуру метода, внутри которого находится этот код.

Вероятно, ещё лучше будет сделать метод `ClassMethod` асинхронным. Но нужно знать, что у него внутри.